# Altium Designer: for some reason I can't use vias

Tags: altium, routing

AD version is 16.0.6.

I have a simple 2-layer PCB. I'm trying to go to the second (bottom) layer, but everything I tried - did not work: "L", "+", "-", "*", etc. Just nothing happens.

Even **Place -> Via** produces nothing.

For "L" I can hear the Windows sound which usually appears when user trying to do something prohibited and there is a zoom out on "-" press.

I have set up the via layer pair and via rules. So I can not understand what can be wrong with my Altium.

Comment: When exactly are you trying to place a via? During a route? Note that the "+" and "-" keys MUST be the ones on the number pad, not along the top of the keyboard (after the 9 and 0 keys). Make sure you don't have another tool in use when you try Place --> Via

Comment: Can you start tracks on top and bottom?

Comment: @DerStrom8, Yes, I'm trying to do it during route. Unfortunately I don't have number KB, so I used the + and - to the right from "0". And finally: I was in a routing tool, while trying "Place->Via"

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, The answer is "yes". I **can** route at the Bottom layer.

Comment: @RomanMatveev There's your problem. You can't use the Place-->Via command while in another tool. You have to exit the routing tool if you want to use Place-->Via. If you want to place a via while in the routing tool you MUST use the + and - keys on the **number** keypad. The ones to the right of the 0 key will NOT work. I generally prefer connecting a full USB keyboard (with the number keypad) to my laptop when using Altium.

Comment: @RomanMatveev If you are using an external mouse you can add a via during routing by changing layers. You route, you press CTRL+SHIFT and you use scroll in your mouse to change layers. The VIA will be added automatically.

Comment: @zdun8 I was not aware of this, thank you for sharing!

Comment: @zdun8 that's worked for me! Thank you very much! Could you post this as an answer to let me accept this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an external mouse you can add a via during routing by changing layers. You route, you press CTRL+SHIFT and you use scroll in your mouse to change layers. The VIA will be added automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` and `-` keys along the top of the keyboard (to the right of the `0` key) will not work to change layers. Altium requires that you use the `+` and `-` keys on the number keypad. If you don't have a number keypad you can do what I do and connect a full USB keyboard to the laptop to give you access to the number pad.

The Place-->Via command will only work when you are not in another tool. If you try to use it while routing (using the routing tool) it will not work.

It sounds like your best bet would be to get a full USB keyboard with a number pad and use that for Altium.

Comment: Another option is to buy just a USB number pad instead of the full keyboard.

Comment: Hm... That looks very bad for Altium. Am I really not able to: 1) redefine shortcuts for my case? 2) Use another shortcut (I found that "L" and "*" should do this as well)?

Comment: The 3D functions are pretty ugly without  a specialized device such as a Spaceview too. I guess they assume that if you can afford their software you can afford a well-outfitted workstation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was unable to place a via under any circumstances, using any of the shortcuts mentioned etc.

I was routing on the bottom layer, and earlier I had hidden the top layer because the planes were showing through and affecting visibility on the bottom layer. The setting is in:

```
View Configuration -> Layers & Colors tab -> Signal And Plane Layers -> Top Layer
```

I guess it makes sense that when the top layer is hidden you can't switch to it by placing a via.

Maybe this will help somebody.